# Problem with Web View Height

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiwebview

I have some problem with webView 
I want know height web view   i use this

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViews
{
    NSLog(@"hight %@",[webViews stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollHeight;"]);
}
```

or

```
document.body.offsetHeight;
```

but for iPad and iPhone i get different height for 1 html?
Who can help or give some advice  about this problem?Tnx

Comment: What is exact difference in pixels? I suspect that your web view for iPhone and iPad has different frame and thus the height to fit in each web view is not equal.

Comment: yes but i want know size of content and not web view frame

Comment: Then my guess may be right, the difference comes from different web view's frame size. If that's the case, you'll have to handle this in your code by setting different heights of the web view for iPhone and iPad.